# Python or other libraries to decipher broken up text

Tags: text, nlp

I am interested in libraries that can decipher text that is disjointed or broken. Disjointed text can sometimes be the result of OCR extraction from scanned documents.

Google's search functionality can make one or two passes and fix such phrases.

For example, of you Google search for "aut omo tiv etran smiss ionflu id", Google will ask if you mean, "automotive transmission ionflu id". If you search on that phrase, Google will then suggest that you search for "automotive transmission fluid".

Are there readily available libraries that can perform this in Python or Java or other tools? Would these necessarily require online connectivity?

I am looking for assistance in finding tools. (Interestingly, I can't get Google's search function to recognize what I am looking for.)

Regards, James Mireles

Comment: I believe this question could be viewed as [off-topic for SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) as you're (in a way) asking for recommendations. I'd suggest rephrasing  it after reading the linked article. In the mean time, what you're fundamentally trying to do is a form of spelling correction, [this article](https://norvig.com/spell-correct.html) by Norvig provides a detailed explanation as to how Google achieves its impressive correction results, and will at least provide a good starting point in your search.

Comment: @KyleFHartzenberg, much obliged. And I can see how this is borderline off-topic. I knew the functionality had to be out there, but before I could ask technical how-to questions, I needed some place to start. I appreciate that you understand what I am looking for and have helped me refine my search terms. I'll read up on your recommendations and see what I turn up.